# apache 2.4 proxypass and redirection mixed

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up ProxyPass for some requests and redirect everything else to different server. It is working partially:
ProxyPass "/Section2/" "http://otherServer/app/Section2/"
Redirect / https://otherServer2/Login

requests to proxied URIs are processed ok. 
There is problem with the Redirect.
If the original request is to  /something/a.php?i=1
it is redirected to https://otherServer2/Loginsomething/a.php?i=1

I want it to be redirected to 
https://otherServer2/Login

How do I do that?
I tried using RewriteRule and  RedirectMatch with the same results.

Comment: After two days of unsuccessful   research, just after I posted question I found the answer: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://otherServer2/Login seems to be working. It still carries over query parameters but I can live with it.

Comment: Well just after I thought I got it running, it now ignores precedent ProxyPass directives and redirects everything.
How this can be configured properly?